# Remove black borders when converting GeoTiff to MBTile with gdal_translate

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, transparency-opacity, mbtiles

I am using gdal_translate to convert a fairly large geoTiff to MBTiles.

As the geoTiff is reprojected, it is not square anymore in Google Mercator and the parts that are not covered appear black when I would like them to be transparent.

I think it could have something to do with the -a_nodata parameter and I have tried with "-a_nodata 0", but it did not change things.

I have tried with both PNG8 and PNG. It did not change things either.

Here is what my command looks like:

```
gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 -of MBTILES -co TILE_FORMAT=PNG8 France.tif france.mbtiles
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just a question; when you reprojected your GeoTiff, did you specify something like  `-dstnodata "255 255 255 0"` to set transparency for the empty space? (I am assuming you data has RGBA bands, as you are trying to make MBTiles-PNG).

Comment: @Kazuhito, I have not reprojected my GeoTIFF to google Mercator, should I ? I will try that.

Comment: Apologies. I assumed the second paragraph of your question was suggesting reprojection as part of your workflow. But, if you can, yes please try to set alpha band and see what happens.

Comment: Setting alpha band alone may not solve your issue. I feel this post [How to add alpha chanel to mbtiles in gdal_translate?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207166/how-to-add-alpha-chanel-to-mbtiles-in-gdal-translate) can be of interest to you.